# Finding capable function in an equation with Mathematica or Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, wolfram-mathematica

I want to find a function **f(xi)** that suffices the following equation:

> (vi-xi)f(xi)'=f(xi)

when xi = k*vi, where vi is a constant and xi is the variable.

Anyone know howto describe this problem in mathematica or matlab? Great Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming. You might want to try http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Would the `i` in `xi` and `vi` be an index? If so, how many different `i` are there, and do you know `vi` for each of them? What is `k`? Does the prime denote derivative? Is `f(x)=0` an acceptable solution? Before describing the problem in mathematica or matlab, first try to describe it more clearly to your fellow humans.

Comment: Thanks@MvG, maybe I will ask for help in mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica

```
eq = (vi - xi) D[f[xi], xi] == f[xi];
DSolve[eq, f[xi], xi]

(* {{f[xi] -> C[1]/(vi - xi)}} *)
```

Matlab

```
syms vi xi f(xi)
dsolve( (vi -xi)*diff(f)==f)

ans =

C2/(vi - xi)
```

Maple

```
restart;
dsolve((vi - xi)*diff(f(xi),xi)=f(xi),f(xi));
(*  f(xi) = _C1/(vi-xi) *)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I think maybe I will ask for further help in math.stackexchange.com.